# Instagram: photo upload confirmation

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, instagram, instagram-api

I have created an android app for our upcoming event. We will allow attendees of the event to network with each other using this app. We will also encourage them to take pictures of the event and share them with a certain #hashtag. Each photo that the user uploads gives them a certain number of reward points. At the end of the event, the user with the maximum points gets a reward for their effort. 
Now I have managed to create a share intent using the instagram documentation here -
[Instagram Android Intent](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/)

However, there is an issue. From this intent I don't know if the user has successfully posted the photo on Instagram or just abandoned the photo share during the editing stage of Instagram.

What would be the best way to accurately establish whether the user has shared the photo on Instagram successfully?

Given that there is a cash reward for a person with maximum shares, we want to be careful in terms of accuracy of calculating the successful shares.

Appreciate any ideas or even workarounds, as long as they meet the end objective.

Also if you think this is impossible to do with relatively high degree of accuracy, please feel free to share your thoughts on why not? We can then at least abandon this approach and work on something else for meaningful sharing and rewarding.

Comment: Pretty sure Instagram doesn't allow you incentivize posting. Facebook doesn't.

Comment: @Wizkid - Thanks for the update. Do you an alternate suggestion on how we can run a successful instagram campaign for our event? Our Marketing department seems to think it can be easily done...

Comment: What can easily be done? I wasn't arguing if what you want to do can be done or not. I was arguing that it is most likely not allowed.

Comment: understood @WizKid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing the share intent I would ask the users their instagram username and save it in your server database. Then, at the end of the event I would use the [Python Client for Instagram API](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram) to retrieve all photos containing your hashtag and photo owner username. Then make a simple sum of photos for each user to know the winner.